# No Latex Rendering at all

Tags: support, mathjax

I can't get any of the tex on any question anywhere to render at all.  I'm on windows7 and I've tried FireFox 15, IE9, Chrome, etc.  all appear the same:  just the original markup is displayed.

I've tried updating, flash, java, disabling all addons, safe-mode, etc.

I can trouble-shoot the problem further, but what underlying technologies are responsible for the actual parsing and rendering of this stuff?  I can't really find the root cause if I don't know that part.  All I know is it's definitely client-side at some level.

Comment: Do formulas render on [MathJax page](http://www.mathjax.org/)?

Comment: Have you checked the error console in your browsers to see if there are any messages there about MathJax?

Comment: Much of MathJax is based on Javascript, do you have that enabled? Is this lack of rendering a recent event (as in, previously you had it working, and now it broke) or has it never worked for you?

Comment: This is currently happening to me (While just answering a problem, it stopped rendering). Those formulas render in my MathJax page. What can I do to resolve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For other people who come across this question: MathJax fails to load if the site is being viewed through HTTPS. Make sure the site is being viewed through regular HTTP (should be `http://` or the URL directly, not `https://`.

Note that HTTPS Everywhere forces HTTPS - if that add-on is enabled, then disable HTTPS Everywhere for just this site, and then reload the page without HTTPS.

Comment: I think that a year and a half ago, *that* wasn't the problem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: How come? No https support 1.5yrs ago?

Comment: Fairly sure it's a recent thing. At least outside SO itself.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hmm well [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) was posted 12/21/2011 saying "So it looks like Stack Exchange now supports HTTPS (to some extent).". Granted, it's still not the default unless you have HTTPS Everywhere or soemthing - if it were then my issue would not have come up